# Is it right if I added the DDL in released version for customers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, versioning

I want to deploy new version for customer, and I want to ensure that database structure will be compatible with new version.

Is it ok in field of software engineering if I added DDL in runtime, for instance

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'person_data' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'hsssoid') BEGIN ALTER TABLE person_data ADD hsssoid varchar(20) END
```

These DDL command will be run everytime the customer calculate the salary.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? a database project is recommended in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it works, but ...

In my opinion I would not use this approach, because the database user running your app must have access to the schema information, which could be a problem in a production environment, specially if you have someone else deploying your application. They would probably add some security restrictions to db user.

The best approach is to add this DDL statement to a deployment script, either automated or manual. You could use a database project to help you to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo.